# What is the starting point in Angular 2 before calling AppComponent.ts?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to to do something at the starting point of angular 2 app but I am unable to get that point. Kindly help me if any one know about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Index.html` is the start and it continuous `main.ts` and then its goes with `<my-app>` and goes on and on.

Comment: How this works: https://wildermuth.com/2016/07/31/Is-Angular2-Too-Full-of-Ceremony

Comment: I have added as a answer. And I will put in more information so that is useful to others soon.

Comment: yes, It will be...

Answer (score 4):

`Index.html` is the start and it continuous `main.ts` and then its goes with `<my-app>` and goes on and on

After Index.html, `systemjs.config.js` is loaded. Which tells which file to run. And in `systemjs.config.js`, it tells to load `main.ts` to get started.

> packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or
>   no extension

After some research, look at the below `systemjs.config.js` file. The comments tell what it does and when.

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      //For android Internet
      'moment': 'npm:moment',
      'jquery':'npm:jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'fullcalendar':'npm:fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      moment: { main: './moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } 
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

`APP_INITIALIZER` is your friend.

It allows you to execute a piece of code, wait for it to complete, and then continue loading your angular application.

Check how to implement:
[Angular: How to correctly implement APP_INITIALIZER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707830/angular-how-to-correctly-implement-app-initializer)