# Angular: How to correctly implement APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a **Angular 5.2.0** application.
I looked up how to implement `APP_INITIALIZER` to load configuration information before the app starts.
Here an extract of the `app.module`:

```
providers: [
    ConfigurationService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (configService: ConfigurationService) =>
            () => configService.loadConfigurationData(),
        deps: [ConfigurationService],
        multi: true
    }
],
```

Here the `configuration.service`:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Configuration } from './configuration';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
    private readonly configUrlPath: string = 'Home/Configuration';
    private configData: Configuration;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        @Inject('BASE_URL') private originUrl: string) { }

    loadConfigurationData() {
        this.http
            .get<Configuration>(`${this.originUrl}${this.configUrlPath}`)
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.configData = {
                    test1ServiceUrl: result["test1ServiceUrl"],
                    test2ServiceUrl: result["test2ServiceUrl"]        
                }
            });
    }

    get config(): Configuration {
        return this.configData;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a constructor of a component where the `configData` is used:

```
export class TestComponent {
    public test1ServiceUrl: string;

    constructor(public configService: ConfigurationService) {
        this.test1ServiceUrl = this.configService.config.test1ServiceUrl;
    }
}
```

It works fine with all the components which are defined within the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. But the same implementation in a component outside the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` does not work.
When I debug the respective constructor of the component where it does not work it says that `configService` is `null`.
Why is the `APP_INITIALIZER` executed before the constructor of a component inside the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is called but not before the constructor of a component outside the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?

Comment: I just discovered the APP_INITIALIZER on another thread and I'm mad that after 6 years of working with angular I haven't known about it. It's going to solve a lot of problems I have. But, the Angular docs provide absolutely zero information on it. I opened up a request with the angular team to get some info on it (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34703).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Due to how `APP_INTIALIZER` [works](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/core/src/application_init.ts#L62), it's expected that asynchronous initializers return promises, but your implementation of `APP_INTIALIZER` multiprovider doesn't because `loadConfigurationData` function doesn't return anything.

It should be something like:

```
loadConfigurationData(): Promise<Configuration> {
  return this.http.get<Configuration>(`${this.originUrl}${this.configUrlPath}`)
  .do(result => {
    this.configData = result;
  })
  .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: How do I do that with HttpClient from @angular/common/http?

Comment: It says: (TS) Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Observable<Configuration>

Comment: This is common Angular/RxJS knowledge that isn't specific to this case. If you use RxJS operator, you need to import it first. You likely did this for other operators. There should be something like `import 'rxjs/add/operator/do`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376972/best-way-to-import-observable-from-rxjs

Comment: One important 'safety tip'.  You really MUST return a Promise... trying to return the observable directly does not work and it doesn't tell you that it won't work, it just... doesn't work.

Comment: `pipe`/`tap` should be used now, instead of `do`.

Comment: + lastValueFrom(...) instead of (...).toPromise()

Answer (score 5):

Do something like

```
 export function StartupServiceFactory(startupService: StartupService) {
      return () => startupService.load();
    }
    const APPINIT_PROVIDES = [
      StartupService,
      {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: StartupServiceFactory,
        deps: [StartupService],
        multi: true,
      },
    ];
```

Startup service

```
load():Promise{
    return new Promise(resolve, reject){
        //load all your configuration 
         resolve(); 
    }

  }
```

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem. The fix was much the same, actually return a promise. 
see: [ngOnInit starts before APP_INITIALIZER is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57516543/ngoninit-starts-before-app-initializer-is-done/57516573#57516573)