# Can you use the Angular app.component to write application settings to local storage?

Tags: angular

Can I use the app component to write settings to local storage and then access the settings from other components?

```
await docRef.get().then(doc => {
   localStorage.setItem("appAdmin", JSON.stringify(doc.data().appAdministrator));
   localStorage.setItem("authorizeDomain", JSON.stringify(doc.data().authorizedDomain));
   localStorage.setItem("contactAdmin", JSON.stringify(doc.data().contactAdministrator));
   localStorage.setItem("contactGroup", JSON.stringify(doc.data().appContactGroup));
});
```

Comment: does it matter? you are calling async method anyway.

Comment: @ABOS I'm not sure. I'm new to Angular. I thought maybe just because the code inside a component was async that did not mean that one component will wait for another.

Comment: Angular APP_INITIALIZER is probably what you want. tons of tutorials online, check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach to your problem would be to provide a factory with the `APP_INITIALIZER` token.

Example:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
            deps: [/* Your dependencies */],
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}

export function appInitializerFactory(/* The injection of your dependencies, in the same order as above */) {
    return () =>
        new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
            // Do your async work, call `resolve()` when done.
        });
}
```

For more information, you can check [here](https://dormoshe.io/articles/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-8) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707830/angular-how-to-correctly-implement-app-initializer).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the answer I have been trying to find. Three Udemy courses on Angular and none of them explained this.

Comment: I implemented your answer successfully. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

for setting up things before any component is used and regardless of the entry point of your app, you might consider using `APP_INITIALIZER`.

> APP_INITIALIZER: Callback is invoked before an app is initialized. All
>   registered initializers can optionally return a Promise. All
>   initializer functions that return Promises must be resolved before the
>   application is bootstrapped. If one of the initializers fails to
>   resolves, the application is not bootstrapped.

ref: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#predefined-tokens-and-multiple-providers

Comment: I agree. However, I picked @tiagodws answer because he used an example. I like examples :)

Comment: @GregHarner you've picked better answer, no doubt about that. i was just wondering about reasons for downvote. all good ;)