# ngOnInit starts before APP_INITIALIZER is done

Tags: angular

APP_INITIALIZER runs a series of nested promises (I've tried subscribes with no difference in the result).

The APP_INITIALIZER needs to get authenticated before it goes to retrieve data from the API server. It also needs to pull two tables from the API server (in sequence).

In api.service, http/get authorization happen in a promise.  After the promise (then), I go to get data from the API service.

The issue is the component ngOnInit() - It attempts to get the variables before they exist.

I have tried the following code in the component, but all that does is call the initData() twice.

```
this.people = await this.apiService.initData();
```

api.service:

```
async initData(): Promise<Person[]> {
        this.userData$ = this.http.get('/.auth/me', {observe: 'response'});
        this.userData$.toPromise().then( res => {
          this.resBody = res.body;
          this.token = res.body[0].access_token;
          this.getLegalSub(this.legalsubdeptsURL)
            .toPromise().then(legalsubdepts => {
              this.legalsubdepts = legalsubdepts;
              this.getPeopleData(this.personURL)
              .toPromise().then(people => {
                this.people = people;
                return this.people;
              });
            });
        });
      }
      return this.people;
    }
```

app.module

```
export function initData(appInitService: APIService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => { 
    return appInitService.initData();
  }
}
...
providers: [
    APIService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initData, deps: [APIService], multi: true }
  ],
```

the component that runs before APP_INITIALIZER is done

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.people = this.apiService.people;
    this.userName = this.apiService.userName;
      console.log("username");
      console.log(this.userName);
  }
```

I need to get the authorization before I can get data from the API server. 
I then need the data from the API server before I process the component.

I eventually get data, but not in time for the component.

Comment: hi! I'm having a similar problem, did you end up keeping the accepted answer?

Comment: yes, although it took some time to get the await to work right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`APP_INITIALIZER`](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#predefined-tokens-and-multiple-providers) is a callback is invoked before an app is initialized. All registered initializers can optionally return a Promise. All initializer functions that return Promises must be resolved before the application is bootstrapped.

In your case, you return a promise but it resolves almost immediately because you do not wait for the response to be finished. You should wait for your promises and you can do this by means of `await` directive

```
async initData(): Promise<Person[]> {
        this.userData$ = this.http.get('/.auth/me', {observe: 'response'});
        await this.userData$.toPromise().then(async res => {
          this.resBody = res.body;
          this.token = res.body[0].access_token;
          return await this.getLegalSub(this.legalsubdeptsURL)
            .toPromise().then(async legalsubdepts => {
              this.legalsubdepts = legalsubdepts;
              return await this.getPeopleData(this.personURL)
              .toPromise().then(people => {
                this.people = people;
                return this.people;
              });
            });
        });
      }
      return this.people;
    }
```

Comment: I think we should avoid using await

Comment: Why so, could you explain a bit more detail?

Comment: As I know, with await you are changing the behaviour of an asynchrous call.
In general we should use .then() callback of promise or subscribe() method of observable instead of await.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer:

in api.service - initData() needs to return a Promise.  The code goes on too far.

```
initAuth(): Promise<any> {
    this.userData$ = this.http.get('/.auth/me', {observe: 'response'});
    return this.userData$.toPromise()
}

initLegalSub(): Promise<any[]> {
   this.initAuth().then( res => {
       this.resBody = res.body;
       this.legalSub$ =  this.getLegalSub(this.legalsubdeptsURL).toPromise();
   });
   return this.legalSub$;
}

initPeople(): Promise<Person[]> {
    this.initAuth().then( res => {
        this.resBody = res.body;
        this.people$ = this.getPeopleData(this.personURL).toPromise();
    });
    return this.people$;
}
```

You'll notice both initLegalSub() and initPeople() call initAuth() - to get the authentication BEFORE they attempt to get data.

THEN, both of these return Promise data - that is used in people.component.

```
constructor( private apiService: APIService ) { 
    this.legalSub$ = this.apiService.initLegalSub();
    this.people$ = this.apiService.initPeople();
  }
```

The initialization of the data happens in the app.module

```
providers: [
    APIService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initPeople, deps: [APIService], multi: true },
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initLegalSub, deps: [APIService], multi: true }],
```

I should put in more logic to determine what to do IF the promise fails, but for now, this allows multiple initializers to happen asynchronously.