# Angular / RxJS - don't repeat the same GET requests during application init

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is there any operator in Angular or RxJS, that would replace several http requests into one, if they are called in short period of time?

---

F.e. when I open my application, all of my 20 components during `ngOnInit` are making the same http call:

[image]

I've created a cache based on Angular HttpInterceptor (f.e. https://blog.logrocket.com/caching-with-httpinterceptor-in-angular/), however because all those calls are performed upon initialization, the cache cannot be built quickly enough.

I could put all components into one parent, that would pass the data to children via Inputs, but I wanted to remain with the architecture, where component can initialize itself (they are reused in other places).

I tried to use RxJS share or share replay, but I'd like to stop sharing after f.e. 1 second. I'd love to put such operator in my service:

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
    return = this.http.get<any>('endpoint')
      .pipe(
        shareIfCalledWithin( 1000ms ),
      );
```

Comment: The parent component is the best idea for you. You can still make your component reusable by adding an additional condition - If there is no data from a parent - make a server request from the child's ngOnInit.

Comment: why not use APP_INITIALIZER? https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER. This makes that before start your application, a function is called. See, e.g. this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707830/angular-how-to-correctly-implement-app-initializer to know how implement it

Comment: @Eliseo I'm also showing those components later, f.e. inside the dialog, with different id Input parameter. Therefore, I cannot preload the data.

Comment: my idea was has a "cache" you always cal to a service functions that return an observables- if not exist `data`, make a httpClient.get using tap to store the value in the variable `data`, if exist, return `of(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to think that the more logic you push in a service the better, and this case seems a good candidate for this approach.

More specifically, as @Fan Cheung has already suggested, I would create a service (shared via Dependency Injection), which exposes 2 APIs

- a method to trigger the execution of the remote service
- an Observable which emits the result of the service call once it arrives

So the code of the service could look like this

```
export class MyService {
  // define a private Subject and then export it as an Observable
  // this Subject emits any time a result is received from the remote service
  // you can use a ReplaySubject if you want chaching
  private _dataFromRemoteService$ = new Subject<any>()
  // API clients can subscribe to to receive the data
  public dataFromRemoteService$ = _dataFromRemoteService$.asObservable()

  // private Subject used as trigger for the fetch operation
  private _trigger$ = new Subject<any>();
  // API to be called to trigger the execution of the remote service
  public fetchData() {
    _trigger.next();
  }
  // private method that subscribes to the trigger and uses debounce to control the number of calls to remote service
  private _fetchData() {
     this._trigger.pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        switchMap(this.http.get<any>('endpoint')
     )
     // the result received from the remote service is broadcasted to all subscribers of dataFromRemoteService$
     .subscribe(_dataFromRemoteService$)
  }
  
  constructor() {
     // start the subscription
     _fetchData();
  }
}
```

Now any Component subscribe to `dataFromRemoteService$` to receive the data once ready and can call the method `fetchData` to trigger the execution of the remote service.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
     // Subscribe to the stream of results of the execution of the service
     this.service.dataFromRemoteService$.subscribe(
        data => {// do something with the data received from remote service}
     )

     // trigger the execution of the service
     this.service.fetchData();
  }
}
```

One of the main advantages of this approach is that you can test the service easily in different situations, e.g. with many clients requesting the remote data in a fast sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Parent component is to provide share data is a good idea.

Another general solution is maybe delegate the http call to a `subject` and fire the http call from this `subject`, `subject` trigger frequency can be controlled by `debounceTime`

```js
const getData = new Subject()
getData.next()
    
const getDataStream = getData.pipe(debounceTime(1000),
switchMap(_ => this.http.get......),
share())
    
getDataStream.subscribe(data => you data...)
```

You can place this logic in a parent component or **shared service.**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, in the meantime I've came up with an upgrade to my cache service, but since it's seems quite over-engineering, I'll probably accept other answer. Still, I believe the below code might be helpful to someone in the future.

Generally, the first request of with the specific type (`urlWithParams`) is stored in `pending`. Until this request is finished, further requests of the same type are stored in `waiting` with corresponding new, empty subject and observable from this subject is returned. When the pending request finishes, it sends the correct HttpResponse to waiting subjects of this type.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpCacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private cache: CoreHttpCacheService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if( req.method !== 'GET' && req.method !== 'OPTIONS' ) {
      this.cache.clear();
    }

    if( req.method !== 'GET' || req.headers.get( CC.NO_CACHE ) ) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    const cachedResponse: HttpResponse<any> = this.cache.get(req.urlWithParams);

    if( this.cache.pending.has( req.urlWithParams ) ) {
      const sbj = new Subject<HttpEvent<any>>();
      this.cache.waiting.push( {r: req.urlWithParams, s: sbj} );
      return sbj.asObservable();
    } else {
      if( cachedResponse ) {
        return of( cachedResponse.clone() );
      } else {
        if( ! this.cache.pending.has( req.urlWithParams ) ) {
          this.cache.pending.add( req.urlWithParams );
        }
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
          tap(stateEvent => {
            if(stateEvent instanceof HttpResponse) {
              this.cache.set(req.urlWithParams, stateEvent.clone());

              let i = this.cache.waiting.length;
              while( i-- ) {
                if( this.cache.waiting[i].r === req.urlWithParams ) {
                  this.cache.waiting[ i ].s.next( stateEvent.clone() );
                  this.cache.waiting.splice( i, 1 );
                }
              }

              this.cache.pending.delete( req.urlWithParams );
            }
          })
        );
      }
    }
  }
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoreHttpCacheService {
  pending = new Set< string >();
  waiting: {r: string, s: Subject<HttpEvent<any>> }[] = [];

  private cache: Map< string, HttpResponse<any> > = new Map();

  private timers = new Map< string, NodeJS.Timer >();

  get( key: string ) {
    return this.cache.get( key );
  }

  set( key: string, v: any ) {
    this.timers.set( key, setTimeout( () => this.clear( key ), Constants.TIME_100SEC ) );
    return this.cache.set( key, v );
  }

  clear( key?: string ) {
    if( key !== undefined ) {
      this.cache.delete( key );
    } else {
      this.cache.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

This example will fail on HTTP error, compares requests only by urlWithParams and CoreHttpCacheService fields are public, so be careful if you'd like to use it.